# What tools exist that can do string matching (ex. regex) websearches?

Tags: search, regex

Is there any web search tool that can do the following:

Perform a web search where one of the keywords is a string pattern,
such as ####suffix, and will match the best result that matches a string with any
four characters+suffix?  Ideally in combination with other keywords.

Answer (score 1):

If you search only for English words which match your pattern you can do the following:

- Go to [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com)
- Make a search for `____suffix`
- Down on the page hover the dog-ear and click on `Copyable Plaintext`
- In the box copy the content of the first field
- Make a Google search for `(`*insert copied text*`)` *your query*

As an example: If you want to search for `____book store`, WolframAlpha search for `____book` results in:

```
bankbook  |  casebook  |  cashbook  |  chapbook  |  cookbook  |  copybook  |  datebook  |  handbook  |  hymnbook  |  notebook  |  overbook  |  passbook  |  playbook  |  rulebook  |  songbook  |  studbook  |  textbook  |  wordbook  |  workbook  |  yearbook
```

(but not including `facebook` for example)

The Google search would be ([link](http://www.google.de/search?q=%28bankbook+|+casebook+|+cashbook+|+chapbook+|+cookbook+|+copybook+|+datebook+|+handbook+|+hymnbook+|+notebook+|+overbook+|+passbook+|+playbook+|+rulebook+|+songbook+|+studbook+|+textbook+|+wordbook+|+workbook+|+yearbook%29+store)):

```
(bankbook | casebook | cashbook | chapbook | cookbook | copybook | datebook | handbook | hymnbook | notebook | overbook | passbook | playbook | rulebook | songbook | studbook | textbook | wordbook | workbook | yearbook) store
```

Alternatively you can make a a list of all possible four letter combinations yourself (note that there are 456,976) and do this search. However I'm sure that Google does not support that many parts in an OR query. Therefore you cannot get a complete ranking of every combination possible using Google.